# Kendo TextBoxFor permitir apenas números em .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validação, kendo-ui

Não quero permitir que o usuário insira caracteres no meu campo **TextBoxFor**, e se o mesmo o fizer, quero exibir uma mensagem informando que o campo deve conter apenas números.

Meu código está abaixo.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.MinVoltage).Name("MinVoltage").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 6em;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal" }))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinVoltage)
```

Minha classe C# está assim:

```
    [Column("MAX_VOLTAGE")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Messages), Name = "MaximumVoltage")]
    [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Somente valores numéricos")]
    [Range(0.1, 99.99, ErrorMessage = "Valores válidos: 0.1 a 99.99 ")]
    public double MaxVoltage { get; set; }
```

**Isso não está funcionando**

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o `type = "number"` no `TextBoxFor`

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.MinVoltage).Name("MinVoltage").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "number", style = "width: 6em;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal" }))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso